# Unable to find code that hides left menu on smaller screens

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been asked to make an update to the left side nav menu on our website whesearchreporting.com (you can enter anything for the username & password, if you'd like to access the site.  Site's still in test mode).  Currently, the nav menu is visible on full width screens, but if you reduce your screen width to around 900px), the menu disappears but can be expanded via a menu toggle icon in the top left. They would now however, like to change this logic to the following, which I'm having problems figuring out how to fix:

- On a full screen, there is no menu toggle button visible in the top left.  The menu always stays open
- On a small or mobile screen, the menu toggle button becomes visible.

So basically, I need to find the code that handles making the left nav menu disappear when the screen size is reduced to around 950px & apply that same logic to the top left menu toggle icon. Is this something handled in bootstrap?

If it helps, here's some of the code that handles making my nav menu smaller or larger (although I don't think it has much to do with making the menu disappear on smaller screens):

```
$(function () {
  $('#sidebar-menu li ul').slideUp();
  $('#sidebar-menu li').removeClass('active');

  $('#sidebar-menu li').on('click touchstart', function() {
    var link = $('a', this).attr('href');

    if(link) { 
      window.location.href = link;
    } else {
      if ($(this).is('.active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $('ul', this).slideUp();
      } else {
        $('#sidebar-menu li').removeClass('active');
        $('#sidebar-menu li ul').slideUp();

        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('ul', this).slideDown();
      }
    }
  });

  $('#menu_toggle').click(function () {
    if ($('body').hasClass('nav-md')) {
      $('body').removeClass('nav-md').addClass('nav-sm');
      $('.left_col').removeClass('scroll-view').removeAttr('style');
      $('.sidebar-footer').hide();

      if ($('#sidebar-menu li').hasClass('active')) {
        $('#sidebar-menu li.active').addClass('active-sm').removeClass('active');
      }
    } else {
      $('body').removeClass('nav-sm').addClass('nav-md');
      $('.sidebar-footer').show();

      if ($('#sidebar-menu li').hasClass('active-sm')) {
        $('#sidebar-menu li.active-sm').addClass('active').removeClass('active-sm');
      }
    }
  });   
});
```

And here's the html for that code section:

```
<div class="nav toggle">
  <a id="menu_toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
</div>
```

Any idea where I should be looking to find the code that handles making that menu disappear on smaller screens?

Thanks

Comment: You need to use media queries. Also, you should cache your jQuery objects, i.e. do this `var $body = $( 'body' );` instead of using `$( 'body' )` everywhere.

Comment: Do you have some CSS on your page? If it contains media-queries, it's probably responsible for the screen-dependant behaviour

Comment: you can do this with media queries in css

Comment: Learn how to work with your browser’s developer tools. Using those, you can easily find out what makes the left column disappear on smaller screens. Switch to responsive mode, inspect the side bar element when it is visible - and then narrow the responsive viewport, until it disappears, then you will see which CSS rule is responsible for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should search for `@media` queries in your `Content/css/custom.css` file

Comment: Thanks for this!  I dug into the media queries & was able to fix my problem with this:    @media (min-width:991px) {
    #menu_toggle {
      display: none;
  }
}